# Entity Framework Core verify SaveChanges count

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have been assigned a task to verify the count of changes done using `SaveChanges()`.
It is expected that the **developer should know how many records will be changed before-hand** when `SaveChanges()` will be called.

To implement it, I have created an extension method for `DbContext` called `SaveChangesAndVerify(int expectedChangeCount)` where I am using transaction and equating this parameter with the return value of `SaveChanges()`.
If the values match, the transaction is committed and if it doesn't match, the transaction is rolled back.

Please check the code below and let me know if it would work and if there are any considerations that I need to make. Also, is there a **better way to do this**?

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static int SaveChangesAndVerify(this DbContext context, int expectedChangeCount)
    {
        context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        var actualChangeCount = context.SaveChanges();
        if (actualChangeCount == expectedChangeCount)
        {
            context.Database.CommitTransaction();
            return actualChangeCount;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Database.RollbackTransaction();
            throw new DbUpdateException($"Expected count {expectedChangeCount} did not match actual count {actualChangeCount} while saving the changes.");
        }
    }

    public static async Task<int> SaveChangesAndVerifyAsync(this DbContext context, int expectedChangeCount, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
        var actualChangeCount = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        if(actualChangeCount == expectedChangeCount)
        {
            context.Database.CommitTransaction();
            return actualChangeCount;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Database.RollbackTransaction();
            throw new DbUpdateException($"Expected count {expectedChangeCount} did not match actual count {actualChangeCount} while saving the changes.");
        }
    }
}
```

A sample usage would be like `context.SaveChangesAndVerify(1)` where a developer is expecting only 1 record to update.

Comment: If the code is working, you could also post it on the Code Review site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes, would be doing that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so some points.

- Unless you've disabled it `SaveChanges` works as a transaction. Nothing will be changed if anything fails

Furthermore use `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` and from there you can get the count of the number of the changed entities. So this will not require you handle transactions. Also `SaveChanges()` simply return the numbers of rows affected so it may not tell the full story.

Generally I dislike the idea of having this kind of check from a project architecture standpoint, increases complexity of code for dynamic changes and simply adds complexity without bringing any kind of security or safety. Data integrity and proper behavior should be validated using Unit test not those kinds of methods. For example you could add Unit Tests that validate that the rows that got changed are the same as those as you expected. But that should be test code. Not code that will be shipped to production

But if you need to do it dont use transaction and count the entities before changing anything as it is much cheaper. You can even use a "cheap" forloop so you can log what entities failed and so on. Furthermore since we are policing the developers you use extensions which means a developer can freely use the `SaveChanges()` as far as I can tell. You should create a new custom class for DbContext and expose only those 2 methods for saving changes.

Comment: Appreciate your time to answer. Will surely check `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()`